# How to fix invalid mount config for type "bind": source path must be a directory in Windows docker Container?

Tags: docker, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, docker-for-windows

I have a keras model (Windows Spyder IDE) and saved for tensorflow serving, and followed the steps in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CUpUPY5g8NE for deploy.

I am using docker-for-windows and running Windows Container (so no shared drive settings in docker)

I pulled TF serving and ran docker with parameters

```
> docker pull tensorflow/serving

> docker run -t --rm -d -p 8500:8500 -p 8501:8501 --name tf_model --mount type=bind,source=$LOCALMODELDIR/tf_model,target=/models/mymodel --mount type=bind,source=$LOCALMODELDIR/models.config,target=/models/models.config -e MODEL_NAME=mymodel tensorflow/serving --model_config_file=/models/models.config
```

I ran to the Error in docker as

```
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": source path must be a directory.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.
```

May I know any fixes.

Comment: As it says in the error output you trying to mount a file which apparently not possible at least from the source side.

Comment: same works in Linux container

Comment: If the target is an empty directory you can move the file to directory contains only model.config and the target is the `/models/` but if model contains some files they will be overwrite so in that case this won't help you.

Comment: I could see this source file mount has kind of support in Kubernetes if the source is in configMap. The docker run is not supported. Sample repo at https://github.com/ms-azure-demos/aks-windows-container-configmap-file-mount-powershell

Answer (score 6):

This is a well known [issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30555) bind mounting files is not possible through windows. Although its possible on linux, there are quite some pitfalls, so mounting a directory is preferred. Also its mentioned that it is a platform limitation on windows itself.